# Setting up OSX keychain for git access

Tags: macos, ssh, git, keychain

I'm setting up a Git server which we will access using SSH, and where the users are authenticated using LDAP.

Is there a way to use `git-credential-osxkeychain` so users don't have to enter their password every time?

I've enabled it but can't find any way to store my username & password.  If I go into the Keychain application directly I'm not sure what information to store so that `git` (via SSH) can find it.

I'd rather not do the standard public/private key thing for SSH - since I'm authenticating with LDAP, there isn't a home directory on the Git server, which means the public key would have to go into my network home folder which is not good for security.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, the GitHub folks created the git-credential-osxkeychain helper, and [their page on setting it up](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) contains this tip:

---

Tip: The credential helper only works when you clone an HTTPS repository URL. If you use the SSH repository URL instead, SSH keys are used for authentication. [This guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) offers help generating and using an SSH key pair.

---

I'm not sure what your security concern is regarding putting your public key in your network home directory. It's your *public* key. It's meant to be *public*.

On the other hand, if your network home directory volume is set to automount and isn't mounted when you're trying to use `git` or `ssh`, it becomes a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem trying to figure out how to get your home directory mounted before you log in, so that you can be authenticated and logged in.